# Не могу скомпилировать python код

Tags: python

Всем привет, я в сием ремесле ещё зелёный, так что извините, за возможные ошибки. После написания кода под питон передо мной встала задача скомпилировать его, но ни на w3c, ни на ютубе нечего внятного не нашлось.
Работаю в Visual studio Code.

Comment: Python - это интерпретируемый язык, он не компилируется.

Comment: Python не компилируемый, а интерпритируемый. Он запускается в реальном времени. Для запуска Python кода нужно установить Python, зайти в директорию проекта через консоль и ввести: python имяфайла.py

Comment: Sergey, только хотел написать

Comment: Также посмотрите документацию от Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-02-writing-code?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все говорят установить пайтон, пайтон не компилируемый и т.д. Вы правы, но может человек хочет готовую программу, т.е. `.exe` файл? Для этого есть модуль `pyinstaller`, используйте его, естественно установив:

`python* -m pip install pyinstaller`

Где `*` версия вашего конкретного питона, если у вас их несколько.

А затем просто выполните эту комманду:

`pyinstaller install ваш_скрипт.py --onefile`

Это даст вам несколько папок, то что нужно вам, находится в папке `dist`

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно было )

Comment: рад помочь, если возникнут проблемы с `pyinstaller`, а они возникают в 70% случаях, обращайтесь